# find the limit in distributions(space of generalized functions)

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

How to find limit in $ \mathcal{D}^{'}$
$$
\exp(itx)(x+i0)^{-1}, t \rightarrow \infty
$$
I try to use Sokhotsky's formula $(x+i0)^{-1} = -i\pi\delta(x) + \rho\frac{1}{x} $  , but did not come to a meaningful answer.

Comment: That thing you're calling Sokhotsky's formula is absurd. What's correct is that $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}(x+i\epsilon)^{-1}$ equals the RHS.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich. I can accept $(x+i0^+)^{-1}$ as a shorthand, but just $0$ is not very meaningful since the limit depends on whether we go from the positive or negative side of $0.$

Comment: Recall that the FT of distributions is continuous and show that $\lim_{t \to \infty} \mathcal F[x \mapsto e^{i t x} (x + i0)^{-1}](w) = 0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f(x + i0)$ and $f(x - i0)$ are notations for the limits from above/below in the complex plane (distributional limits in this case), similar to $f(x + 0)$ and $f(x - 0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sokhotsky's formula, what we want to calculate is
$$
e^{itx} \left( -i\pi\delta(x) + \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \right)
= -i\pi \left( e^{itx} \delta(x) + e^{itx} \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x} \right)
.
$$

The first term is easy, using $f\delta=f(0)\delta$:
$$
e^{itx} \delta(x) = e^{it0} \delta(x) = \delta(x)
.
$$

For the second term we first use a couple of definitions:
$$
\langle e^{itx} \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}, \phi(x) \rangle
= \langle \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}, e^{itx} \phi(x) \rangle
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} e^{itx} \phi(x) \, dx
.
$$
Then we note that because of symmetry only the odd part of $e^{itx}\phi(x)$ matters. The odd part equals
$$
\cos tx\ \phi_{\text{odd}}(x) + i \sin tx\ \phi_{\text{even}}(x)
.
$$

For the first of these terms we use the fact that there exists $\psi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\phi_{\text{odd}}(x) = x\psi(x).$ This gives
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \cos tx\ \phi_{\text{odd}}(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \cos tx\ x\psi(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \cos tx\ \psi(x) \, dx
\\= \int \cos tx\ \psi(x) \, dx
\to 0 \text{ as }t\to\infty.
$$

For the second term we have
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \sin tx\ \phi_{\text{even}}(x) \, dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\sin tx}{x} \ \phi_{\text{even}}(x) \, dx
= \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\sin tx}{x} \ \phi_{\text{even}}(x) \, dx
\\
\to \pi\phi_{\text{even}}(0) \text{ as } t\to\infty.
$$
But $\phi_{\text{even}}(0) = \phi(0)$ so this just becomes $\pi\phi(0).$

I leave it to you to summarize the result.